# Como excluir ambos valores duplicados do array?

Tags: php, array

Recebo dois `arrays`

Porém preciso que ao fundi-los, os valores que forem iguais sejam retirados:
em

```
array_unique( array_merge($array1, $array2) )
```

É possível remover os duplicados, mas quero remover ambos os duplicados.

Existe um método simples, ou é looping mesmo?

Comment: Dê um exemplo da estratura dos arrays, facilitará na compreensão do problema e solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode remover os itens duplicados e o respectivos singulares fazendo a difenreça dos arrays duas vezes a de `$a` com `$b` e de `$b` com `$a`.

A primeira chamada de `array_diff()` retorna os elmentos: 3, 30 e 40 e a segunda: 70 e 80

```
$a1 = array(1, 2, 3, 5, 30, 40,99);
$a2 = array(1, 2, 5, 80, 70, 99);

$n = array_merge(array_diff($a1, $a2) , array_diff($a2, $a1));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($n);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 40
    [3] => 80
    [4] => 70
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) e atualizar os arrays antigos:

```
$array_antes = array_intersect($array_antes, $array_concatenado);
```